# is there a difference between al and dl?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

First, it is my first assembly. And I use it with "NASM" and "64bit ASM" and "Intel" code and Mac OS.

When I try to write strdup function, it didn't work with al.
In using my strdup function, the string was broken.
So, my code is here.

```
    global _strdup
    extern _malloc

    section .text
_strdup:
    xor rcx, rcx
    jmp strlen
strlen:
    cmp [rdi + rcx], byte 0
    je malloc
    inc rcx
    jmp strlen
malloc:
    inc rcx
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rcx
    call _malloc
    pop rdi
    cmp rax, 0
    je error
    xor rcx, rcx
    jmp copy
copy:   
    mov al, byte [rdi + rcx]
    mov byte [rax + rcx], al
    cmp al, byte 0
    je return
    jmp increment
increment:
    inc rcx
    jmp copy
error:  
    mov rax, 0
    ret
return: 
    ret
```

But, when I write same code with dl not al, it works!

```
    global _strdup
    extern _malloc

    section .text
_strdup:
    xor rcx, rcx
    jmp strlen
strlen:
    cmp [rdi + rcx], byte 0
    je malloc
    inc rcx
    jmp strlen
malloc:
    inc rcx
    push rdi
    mov rdi, rcx
    call _malloc
    pop rdi
    cmp rax, 0
    je error
    xor rcx, rcx
    jmp copy
copy:   
    mov dl, byte [rdi + rcx]
    mov byte [rax + rcx], dl
    cmp dl, byte 0
    je return
    jmp increment
increment:
    inc rcx
    jmp copy
error:  
    mov rax, 0
    ret
return: 
    ret
```

I don't know why `dl` works and the difference between `al` and `dl`.
Anyone know about it? Thanks.

Comment: `al` is the low byte of `rax` which you use for adressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al` is the smallest part of `rax` while `dl` is the smallest part of `rdx`. Changing `al` will change the value of `rax` as well.

Why your code is not working with `al`?

```
copy:   
    mov al, byte [rdi + rcx] ; you move "byte [rdi + rcx]" in "al"
                             ; thus changing the value of "rax" as well.
                             ; the result of the following statement becomes unexpected
    mov byte [rax + rcx], al
```

But when you do it with `dl`, `rax` is not affected and hence your program works as expected.

Try the following code and run it through debugger to see the effect of changing the value of `al` on `rax:

```
section .text
    global main
main:
    nop

    mov rax, 1000
    mov al, byte 10

    nop
```

Result:

After `mov rax, 1000`, value of `rax`: 1000

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  00000011 11101000
```

After `mov al, 10`, value of `rax`: 778

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  00000011 00001010
                                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

So, changing `al` will affect `rax`.